# How to await inside setInterval in JS?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await, puppeteer

I have a code segment that looks like this:

```
async function autoScroll(page, maxDate = null) {
  await page.evaluate(async () => {
    await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
            let lastScrollTop = 0;

            const interval = setInterval(async () => {
                window.scrollBy(0, scrollHeight);
                const scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
                let lastDate = null;

                if (maxDate) {
                    const html = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document.doctype) + document.documentElement.outerHTML;

                    await extractDate(html).then((date) => {
                        lastDate = date;
                    });
                }

                if (scrollTop === lastScrollTop || 
                    (maxDate && lastDate && maxDate.getTime() >= lastDate.getTime())) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    resolve();
                } else {
                    lastScrollTop = scrollTop;
                }
            }, 2000);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
            reject(err.toString());
        }
    });
});
}
```

Where `extractDate` method has the following form:

```
function extractDate(html) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // Rest removed for brevity.
        resolve(result);
    });
}
```

Now the problem is that, my code keeps scrolling, but it doesn't wait for the other stuff inside `setInterval` to finish, as it keeps scrolling every 2 seconds, but normally `extractDate` function should take longer than 2 seconds, so I actually want to await for everything inside `setInterval` to finish before making the call to the new interval.

Because of the async nature of stuff, I didn't manage to `console.log` stuff so see the behavior of the code.

So, how can I make sure that everything inside `setInterval` finishes before making the next interval call?

**EDIT:**

This solution using `setTimeout` scrolls just once and throws unhandled promise rejection error with puppeteer.

```
 async function autoScroll(page, maxDate = null) {
     await page.evaluate(async () => {
        await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            try {
               const scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
               let lastScrollTop = 0;

                const interval = async function() {
                    window.scrollBy(0, scrollHeight);
                    const scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
                    let lastDate = null;

                    if (maxDate) {
                        const html = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document.doctype) + document.documentElement.outerHTML;
                        await extractDate(html).then((date) => {
                            lastDate = date;
                        });
                    }

                    if (scrollTop === lastScrollTop || 
                       (maxDate && lastDate && maxDate.getTime() >= lastDate.getTime())) {
                        resolve();
                    } else {
                        lastScrollTop = scrollTop;
                        setTimeout(interval, 2000);
                    }
                }

                setTimeout(interval, 2000);

            } catch (err) {
                console.error(err);
                reject(err.toString());
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: What’s the error in the rejection?

Comment: @Aankhen It just scrolls once, and then after some time it throws `Error: protocol error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Promise was collected`. Stack trace points to some puppeteer functions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Turn the interval function into a *recursive `setTimeout` function* instead, that way you can initialize a timeout for the next iteration once the function has finished.

```
async function doScroll() {
  window.scrollBy(0, scrollHeight);
  const scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  let lastDate = null;
  if (maxDate) {
    const html = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document.doctype) + document.documentElement.outerHTML;
    await extractDate(html).then((date) => {
      lastDate = date;
    });
  }
  if (scrollTop === lastScrollTop ||
      (maxDate && lastDate && maxDate.getTime() >= lastDate.getTime())) {
    // No need to `clearInterval`:
    resolve();
  } else {
    lastScrollTop = scrollTop;
    // Recursive setTimeout:
    setTimeout(doScroll, 2000); // <------------------
  }
}
setTimeout(doScroll, 2000);
```

Comment: You would put all that inside the `try` block - everything else would be the same

Comment: Please check my edited code with your solution. I tried that but using that approach it just scrolls once. No matter whether I comment out the if statement that includes the await call. Where previously it was scrolling all the time until if condition was satisfied.

Comment: what is this resolve() call ? it is not defined in the block. also, shouldn't it be scroll() instead of scroll ?

Comment: @NirO. This is what the code inside the `try` block should be. `resolve` is defined outside, in `await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {`

Answer (score 39):

Use the following code:

```
setInterval(async () => {
    await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos") 
}, 100);
```

Comment: Thank you! I was searching for this solution very long time)

Comment: beware of https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/v2.28.0/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-misused-promises.md setInterval will receive a promise which it doesn't understand

Comment: @genuinefafa `setInterval` will receive _a function_ that returns a promise, but it won't receive the promise itself. As far as I know, `setInterval` disregards the return values of the called function.

Answer (score 21):

I generally opt for this solution.  I think it's cleaner:

```
function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
}

async function loop() {
  while (/* condition */) {
    /* code to wait on goes here (sync or async) */    

    await delay(100)
  }
}
```

Your `loop` function will return a promise.  You can wait for it to stop looping, or you can discard it.

Comment: This is absolutely smooth.

I'm transitions my calls out of mssqlserver into node, and this resolves the logic steps that functions posted by others fail to account for: fully complete the statement before initiating any delay.

Comment: This is beautiful

Comment: Slick! thanks for this!

Comment: Brilliant solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Make the interval a function instead and use setTimeout to queue the future function call.

```
const interval = async function () { // instead of setInterval
```

Then use setTimeout function where you want to to queue the future call:

```
setTimeout(interval, 2000);
```

Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/t9apy3ec/5/

Comment: Try moving the interval function to the top of the parent promise function, and move the try catch block inside the interval. And at the promise line, try returning the promise and remove the async keyword from the promise function.

Comment: Can you write it here as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If someone wants an updated solution there is react-timeout which cancels any lingering timers automatically when wrapped component is unmounted.

More info

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-timeout

npm i react-timeout
```

While using await you can do something like this

```
  handleClick = async() => {
    try {
      await this.props.getListAction().then(()=>{
        this.timeOut = this.props.setTimeOut(this.handleClick, 10000);
      });

    } catch(err) {
      clearTimeout(this.timeOut);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Usually is not a good thing to mix `await` and `then` syntaxes as it will create more confusion.

Answer (score 0):

When using an async function as an argument to `setInterval` or `setTimeout`, make sure you wrap any operations that can throw errors in a try/catch to avoid un-handled errors and, on Node.js, do not call `process.exit` as it will pre-empt the event loop without any respect for timers. More detail in [Async, Promises, and Timers in Node.js](https://blog.atomist.com/javascript-timer-settimeout/).